# Writing a Hilbert-style Proof for $(A ∧ (¬B)) ⊢ (¬(A → B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, hilbert-calculus

I've been trying to write a Hilbert-style proof using the Axioms and Rules of Inference for propositional logic, but I keep getting stuck at step 3.

$$(A ∧(¬B))  ⊢ (¬(A → B)$$

1. $(A ∧ (¬B))$ (Hypothesis)
2. $A = ¬B = (A ∨ ¬B)$ (Golden Rule, eqn)
3. $A = (A → ¬B)$ (Implication, Leib, c-part A=P, p-fresh)

Comment: $\Delta$ isn't usual for "and" ; use preferably $\land$ written `\land`.

Comment: You can use the commands "\cap", "\implies" and "\neg" written in between dollar signs to write $\cap, \implies$ and $\neg$ respectively.

Comment: @JeanMarie It's written in the post $\Delta$ means "and".

Comment: What are the available rules?

Comment: We may use different strategies, using the fact that $A \land (\lnot B) \vdash A$ and $A \land (\lnot B) \vdash \lnot B$. Thus, we may start with assumptions $A, \lnot B, A \to B$. Using Implication we get: $A, \lnot B, \lnot A \lor B$.

Comment: Then, using $A \equiv A \lor \bot$ and Cut we get: $A,¬B, A \to B \vdash B$ that with $A,¬B, A \to B \vdash \lnot B$ we get $A,¬B, A \to B \vdash \bot$.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use an "equational style" proof: by De Morgan and DN $A ∧(¬B) \equiv \lnot (\lnot A \lor B)$ and using Implication: $¬(A \to B)$

Comment: Without clear axioms, you cannot prove anything in a [Hilbert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms). You have to clarify which formulas are allowed to be used.